# How to localize iOS settings bundle?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, settings-bundle, ios-settings-bundle

I added English string to title, what about other languages? Also how to auto generate **Root strings** files for current titles?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fount out..

**Apple/Xcode** developers just didn't really implement anything in **Xcode** to automate this process

we have to manually create the next structure using **Finder**:

```
Settings.bundle:
    Root.plist
    en.lproj:
        Root.strings
    ru.lproj:
        Root.strings
```

**en.lproj**, **ru.lproj** folders

**Root.strings** - file

p.s. you won't see **Root.strings** in **Xcode**, you need to find it in **Finder** and edit it using **TextEdit**